# RequireJS and multiple compiled Handlebar.js templates in a single file

Tags: javascript, maven, requirejs, handlebars.js

I'm new to RequireJS.  I'm using **RequireJS** and **Handlebars.js** together in a Java/Maven application.

I'm also using **[jknack's handlebars-maven-plugin](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java/tree/master/handlebars-maven-plugin)** to compile my Handlebars templates.  The templates need to be compiled in order for them to work as part of a cross-domain solution.

The plugin is compiling my templates and merging them into a single file.  The resulting file (let's call it *template.js*) contains something like:

```
define('a.template', ['handlebars'], function(Handlebars) {
  ...
  var templates = Handlebars.templates = Handlebars.templates || {};
  templates['a.template'] = template;
  var partials = Handlebars.partials = Handlebars.partials || {};
  partials['a.template'] = template;
  return template;
}
define('b.template', ['handlebars'], function(Handlebars) {
  ...
  var templates = Handlebars.templates = Handlebars.templates || {};
  templates['b.template'] = template;
  var partials = Handlebars.partials = Handlebars.partials || {};
  partials['b.template'] = template;
  return template;
}
```

After a little reading I believe these are named templates (which I understand is not best practice) but the plugin generates them like this and I'd rather not hand edit the generated files to remove the names in case in the future the templates change and somebody else on my team has to regenerate them.

Now I want to load my compiled Handlebar templates from the single file and use them with RequireJS.  After much messing about I've managed to get something that appears to work:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'handlebars': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.min',
    'template': 'template'
  },
  shim: {
    'handlebars': {
      exports: 'handlebars'
    },
    'template': {
      exports: ['a.template','b.template']
    },
    'a.template': ['template'],
    'b.template': ['template'],
  }
});
define(['a.template', 'b.template'],
    function (aTemplate, bTemplate) {
...
```

However, I see an error when I load the page:

> **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

I've tracked this down to the "*getGlobal*" function in RequireJS (I think it is the attempted **split**).  So it seems to be having an issue that the exports attribute for 'template' is an array rather than a string.

The templates appear to be working as I would expect.

---

I'm not sure if what I'm doing is wrong and there is a better way to load multiple compiled templates from a single file?

**OR**

Have I uncovered a bug in RequireJS or jknack's maven plugin?

Comment: Why are you doing `exports: ['a.template','b.template']` . This is used when you want some globals to be returned as part of require call and I dont think we have anything like "a.template" in global.... this might be causing the problem because of string with a dot "." in it. Just remove this and tell us if it works...

Comment: It doesn't.  Somehow it seems to be the exports that inform the following lines in the shim that 'a.template' is a function and not a file.

Comment: Without the exports line, the page stops working and I see errors such as  "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)", "Uncaught Error: Script error for: a.template"

Comment: Do you mean that the dot in the template name is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following working without the JavaScript error.

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'handlebars': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.min',
    'a.template': 'template',
    'b.template': 'template'
  },
  shim: {
    'handlebars': {
      exports: 'handlebars'
    }
  }
});
define(['a.template', 'b.template'],
    function (aTemplate, bTemplate) {
...
```